# error handling with BeautifulSoup when scraped url doesn't respond

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm totally noob to python so please forgive my mistake and lack of vocabulary. I'm trying to scrap some url with BeautifulSoup. My url are coming from a GA api call and some of them doesn't respond.

How do I build my script so that BeautifulSoup ignore the url that doesn't return anything ?

Here is my code :

```
  if results:
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      rawdata.append(row[0])
  else:
    print 'No results found'

  urllist = [mystring + x for x in rawdata]

  for row in urllist[4:8]:  

    page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')


    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    share = name_box.text.strip() 

    # save the data in tuple
    sharelist.append((row,share))

  print(sharelist)
```

I tried to use this :

```
  except Exception: 
  pass
```

but I don't know where and got some syntax error. I've look at other questions, but cannot find any answers for me.

Comment: You need a `try` before an `except`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the value of `name_box` variable - it would be `None` if nothing found:

```
for row in urllist[4:8]:  
    page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    if name_box is None:
        continue

    # ...
```

Comment: I guess it's working but I can't really check because now I have the following error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)`